# SSRS - same PDF report (rdl file), different line height on different systems

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, pdfrenderer

When reports from our system in Singapor where copied to our system in Germany they show different formatting: The generated PDF report in Germany has more space between the lines and the footer is not visible.
When reducing the top and bottom padding of the text fields from 2p to 1p the lines are nearly equally high and the footer is back in place.

Checked differences, but not found:

- both SQL 2008 R2
- same version of report viewer
- same configuration of report viewer
- same font used
- report solution was also copied - no difference

Where can I look for differences? I thought the formatting was only done in rdl file itself? Any Ideas? Please ask for more of my system details, if needed. Thanks.

**Additional information from my side:** 
I generate both reports (same report on different systems) on the same browser and download and open both PDF on the same system with the same Acrobat Reader - so screen resolution is also the same. PDF Properties as Page Size and PDF Producer and Version is also the same.

[anonymized report: left Singapor - right Germany](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FZv3.jpg)

Comment: Tablix row heights when the report is rendered; by default a row will adjust to the height of its content means row will grow taller than the set row Height to accommodate the text.  If the effect is not desirable then you can change the CanGrow property to False .. Try with this, Set CanGrow Property to False for a row and let us know if problem persists then probably the issue in report server configuration or Different screen resolution ..

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but CanGrow property is needed in some of our 70 reports. The different rendering is occurring in all reports. And all reports show correctly on the Singapor system (CanGrow works correctly there).
Perhaps you would like to add some ideas on your las remarks 'report server configuration' and  'Different screen resolution'.
I add som Additional Infos on my start post above.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Preview Mode - Click button to the right of the Print Icon called [PRINT LAYOUT].

[image]

Here, you can manipulate the header/footer and margin size in order to fit everything in your report on one page.

Once you've done this, you should be able to go back into the report, right-click outside of the report, or inside the header/Footer and change the properties. You can change the length to the sizes you chose in preview mode that fit everything into your screen. Let me know if this helps
[image]

Comment: As I understand, these are settings for the report and would change the rdl file, right? If true, that would not be the final needed solution. Reports are further developed on the Singapor system same as here in Germany. So the rdl files must be the same and untouched. 
There must be a setting, dll, configuration except the rdl file, that is causing the differences in formatting (different line height/ missing footer). But thank you very much for you work.

Comment: When in Preview Layout for the reports in both systems, are the settings i mentioned above the same - is Orientation/paper size and Margins all = ?

Comment: Yes, all settings in preview mode are the same.

Comment: This may be a silly question but have you ruled out the printer settings  in both cases? It seems the report is correct in terms of Report Properties/Margins/Etc. but the printer wants to either shrink to fit, double side, change some type of setting to print it 9 pages longer?